# How to change textsize and widget size according to screen in flutter?

Tags: android, android-layout, flutter, flutter-layout

How to change `textsize`, `widgetsize`, `padding` according to screen size?

1st Screen :

```
screenHeight:640.0
screenWidth:360.0
PixelRatio:2.0
TextScaleFactor:1.0
```

2nd Screen :

```
screenHeight:912.0
screenWidth:540.0
PixelRatio:2.0
ScaleFactor:1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather using hard coded values, you can use [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) to get the screen size and according to that, you can adjust your widget's height, width. In most cases hard coded values may throw an error due to different screen sizes of different devices.

For your screen to be of specific height, wrap it in a widget that has size properties, like

```dart
Container(height: YOUR_HEIGHT, width: YOUR_WIDTH, child: HOME())
```

Comment: That is what i am asking. How to use mediaQuery for changing font size according to screens.

Comment: for height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
for width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width